# Quick question, how to open the active contents of a tab on a different container instead of right below it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap and need the "vertical tabs" to open it's each individual content in a container next to it, not below itself.

I've tried to understand what:
class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab"
means so I can display it's content on a container right next to it. Sort of like a "navigation bar" situation except the content keeps appearing at the bottom.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="css/mobile.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-1">
            <div id="side" class="fullcontainer">
                <div class="container">
                  <img class="fullimage" src="gerege.png">

                </div>

                    <div id="sidebar" class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
                            <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
                            <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
                            <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
                            <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">...</div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">...</div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">...</div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">...</div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                        <div id="main" class="fullcontainer">
                          <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="horizontal">
                            <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
                            <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
                            <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
                            <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings"  role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
                            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">...</div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">CONTENT INSIDE THE TAB, I AM THE CONTENT INSIDE THE TAB AND I KEEP APPEARING AT THE BOTTOM, CODER DOES NOT KNOW HOW TO CUSTOMIZE ME DUE TO HIS FRAMEWORK INEXPERIENCE.</div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">...</div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">...</div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The content inside each tab keeps appearing at the bottom of the tabs. I want it to appear on the container next to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Wrap` both tab and content div in `<div class="d-flex"></div>` like below

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
<div class="container-1">
   <div id="side" class="fullcontainer">
      <div class="container">
         <img class="fullimage" src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2019/india-elections-2019-6586551400660992-l.png">
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex">
         <div id="sidebar" class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
            <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
            <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
         </div>
         <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">Home</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">Profile</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">Messages</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">Settings</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="main" class="fullcontainer d-flex">
      <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="horizontal">
         <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
         <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
         <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
         <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings"  role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
         <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">...</div>
         <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">CONTENT INSIDE THE TAB, I AM THE CONTENT INSIDE THE TAB AND I KEEP APPEARING AT THE BOTTOM, CODER DOES NOT KNOW HOW TO CUSTOMIZE ME DUE TO HIS FRAMEWORK INEXPERIENCE.</div>
         <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">...</div>
         <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">...</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, I figured this out while waiting for an answer but am still thrilled that it is the same as someone who's also figured it out, giving me much needed reassurance.

Comment: @nimbleclouds glad that it helped